# How to extract text using xpath?

Tags: xpath

I am very new to Xpath and html. Could anyone please tell me how to use xpath to extract the text ('Nicht verfugbar') shown in the attached pic?
[image]
Thanks a lot!

The web page I am talking about here is
https://de.louisvuitton.com/deu-de/produkte/nano-speedy-monogram-010575

Comment: Please edit your question and add the actual html, not a picture, and make sure it's properly closed (for example, starts and ends with `<div>`.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for your reply. The html content is very long and I don't know how to display the file in a nice indented format. But I address your comment by attaching a more completed picture, where the structure of the html should be clear enough. Also the webpage address is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
//span[@class='lv-stock-indicator lv-product-stock-indicator lv-product__stock list-label-m -not-available']/text()
```

The class of the span is unique, so it can be used for location.

More info:
https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your way, but got only empty list [].